# Cross-platform access to C constants

Tags: c, cross-platform, c-preprocessor

Is there a cross-platform (ie, across Linux, BSD, & OS X, ideally all of POSIX) I can get programmatic access to constants like `O_RDWR`, based purely on the string `"O_RDWR"`?  I am writing some (non-C) code that interoperates with C functions across platforms and needs to call, eg, open(2) with the correct parameters - but I have no guarantee as far as what the local system sets its constants to.

I'm essentially looking for something like `get_constant_value("O_RDWR") -> "02"`.

EDIT:
I currently have a really nasty hack: directly invoke the preprocessor and examine the output.

```
printf "#include <fcntl.h>\nO_RDWR" | cpp | tail -n 1
```

Comment: This is typically done by compiling some C code on every target platform you're interested in which maps the integer literal to a string and then doing some kind of lookup.  For example, Python has constants for these in the [`os` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#open-constants), which are defined via the `posix` module in [`posixmodule.c`](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Modules/posixmodule.c?view=markup) (take a look around line 8992).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such thing as of today. In C# this is called reflection. There are rumors that C++ committee discusses reflection for C++14. Once it will be adopted, well in 1-3 yeas you can expect this will be supported in compilers.

If the number of constants that you need is limited, you may want to write your custom code that will do the translation.